# jQuery Mobile .NET form breaks android

Tags: .net, android, mobile, jquery-mobile

Im developing a site using jquery mobile and it has been reported that dropdowns are not working in android for pages that are rendered through the .NET cms.

I've narrowed down the issue to be the form element that wraps all content on a .NET page. I've tested both with and without the form and the form is definitely the culprit. The with form vers works on iPhone and other smartphones that were tested, so this is specific to Android.

Anyone who has run into this and has some insight to share would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Excuse the absence of code but this is easily reproducible for any jQuery Mobile site. If someone can point to an example where a .net form is used and andriod is responding to form elements properly that would be helpful too.

Answer (score 0):

I received a response (https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/1625#comment_1154114) from a maintainer of the jqm project on the bug I posted, that they will not be attempting to resolve this on their end, which is just as well as it really needs to be done on the .NET site.

We ended up solving this by adding the form element just inside the data-role=page element which made the android devices in question happy.